# "containsPoint" difference between v 1.7.2 and v 2.3.1

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I've returned to a FabricJS project done in v 1.7.2 and am getting an error with v 2.3.1 that I haven't been able to sort out. I guess things have changed a lot between these versions.

The error is occurring on the "containsPoint" call in the snippet below:

```
if (event.e.ctrlKey && canvas.containsPoint(event.e, canvas.backgroundImage)) {
  // code removed for clarity
}
```

I am trying to test if the mouse event is occurring withing the rect of the canvas backgroundImage.

From the console, the code is failing with error `Cannot read property 'tl' of null` in the `_getImageLines: function(oCoords)` function call because the argument `oCoords` is null.

The v1.7.2 code has a test for `oCoords` and sets them if they don't exist. If I patch that test into v2.3.1, the error doesn't occur.

Can someone explain what has changed between versions or point me to an explanation? I don't want to hack v2.3.1. Should I be calling `setCoords()` before calling `containsPoint()`?

Also, (for additional confusion) although the 2.3.1 version of `containsPoint` allows for parameters to be passed, in my usage, I am not able to pass parameters because the function is called indirectly.

(Sorry this is so long!)

---

version: "1.7.2"

```
   /**
     * Checks if point is inside the object
     * @param {fabric.Point} point Point to check against
     * @return {Boolean} true if point is inside the object
     */
    containsPoint: function(point) {
      if (!this.oCoords) {
        this.setCoords();
      }
      var lines = this._getImageLines(this.oCoords),
          xPoints = this._findCrossPoints(point, lines);

      // if xPoints is odd then point is inside the object
      return (xPoints !== 0 && xPoints % 2 === 1);
    },
```

---

version: '2.3.1'

This `containsPoint` function calls the `containsPoint` function at the bottom of the page.

```
 /**
     * Checks if point is contained within an area of given object
     * @param {Event} e Event object
     * @param {fabric.Object} target Object to test against
     * @param {Object} [point] x,y object of point coordinates we want to check.
     * @return {Boolean} true if point is contained within an area of given object
     */
    containsPoint: function (e, target, point) {
      // console.log('cp',e, target, point);

      var ignoreZoom = true,
          pointer = point || this.getPointer(e, ignoreZoom),
          xy;

      if (target.group && target.group === this._activeObject && target.group.type === 'activeSelection') {
        xy = this._normalizePointer(target.group, pointer);
      }
      else {
        xy = { x: pointer.x, y: pointer.y };
      }

      // http://www.geog.ubc.ca/courses/klink/gis.notes/ncgia/u32.html
      // http://idav.ucdavis.edu/~okreylos/TAship/Spring2000/PointInPolygon.html      
      return (target.containsPoint(xy) || target._findTargetCorner(pointer));
    },
```

---

```
   /**
     * Checks if point is inside the object
     * @param {fabric.Point} point Point to check against
     * @param {Object} [lines] object returned from @method _getImageLines
     * @param {Boolean} [absolute] use coordinates without viewportTransform
     * @param {Boolean} [calculate] use coordinates of current position instead of .oCoords
     * @return {Boolean} true if point is inside the object
     */
    containsPoint: function(point, lines, absolute, calculate) {

      var lines = lines || this._getImageLines(
            calculate ? this.calcCoords(absolute) : absolute ? this.aCoords : this.oCoords
          ),
          xPoints = this._findCrossPoints(point, lines);

      // if xPoints is odd then point is inside the object
      return (xPoints !== 0 && xPoints % 2 === 1);
    },
```

---

```
 /**
     * Method that returns an object with the object edges in it, given the coordinates of the corners
     * @private
     * @param {Object} oCoords Coordinates of the object corners
     */
    _getImageLines: function(oCoords) {      
      return {
        topline: {
          o: oCoords.tl,
          d: oCoords.tr
        },
        rightline: {
          o: oCoords.tr,
          d: oCoords.br
        },
        bottomline: {
          o: oCoords.br,
          d: oCoords.bl
        },
        leftline: {
          o: oCoords.bl,
          d: oCoords.tl
        }
      };
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in doc [canvas.containsPoint](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#containsPoint), require fabric object as second argument. If `canvas.backgroundImage` is not null then it should work. And [object.containsPoint](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#containsPoint) require point, and imageline as second argument.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas',{
 width: 400,
 height: 400
});
var rect = new fabric.Rect({width:100,height:100});
canvas.add(rect);
canvas.on('mouse:down',function(option){
 //if(canvas.containsPoint(option.e,rect)) console.log('inside rect');
 if(rect.containsPoint(option.e)) console.log('inside rect')
})
```

```css
#myCanvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.7/fabric.js"></script>-->
<canvas id="myCanvas" ></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, narrowed this down:

As noted above, Fabric v1.7.2 had this check in the `containsPoint` function:

```
   if (!this.oCoords) {
        this.setCoords();
   }
```

In my revised code, if I make the `setCoords()` call before calling `containsPoint` then there is no error. I have not come across any explanation for the change, assume it is for performance.

```
canvas.backgroundImage.setCoords();

if (event.e.ctrlKey && canvas.containsPoint(event.e, canvas.backgroundImage)) {
  // do some cool stuff
}
```

Another difference between v1.7.2 and 2.3.1 I've come across is that `canvas.backgroundImage` no longer has a `getWidth()` function. Instead `width` and `height` are now properties.